# Issue while implementing parallel test execution in VSTS 2017

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have created one build definition in VSTS and map a test plan having 6 test cases to execute those on Hosted agent(having 2 machine).
We have added two remote agent on a single  azure pool which I am targeting as environment for the run agent of build definition.

**Agenda**- We want that test cases should be distributed run time on both Hosted agent to achieve parallel execution.
Means- 3 test cases per machine should be pick.

Can any one please help us to do ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the agent phases and select `Multi-Agent` with `Visual Studio Test` task.

Please see [Testing with unified agents and phases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/test-with-unified-agent-and-phases#advantages-of-using-the-unified-agent) for details.

Related document: [Phases in Build and Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/phases#agent-phase)

Similar thread for your reference : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4742

Comment: @Rohini Kumari Any update? Have you resolved the issue?